# Почему нельзя увеличивать массив на ходу?

Tags: c, массивы

```
void average()
{   int ctr=1;
    int averagenum[ctr];
    for (int i = 0; i<ctr;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d-ый элемент:", i);
        scanf("%d", &averagenum[i]);
        if(averagenum[i]!=0)
        ctr++;
    }
}
```

Почему так нельзя? Или можно, но я что-то не понял?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы выделяете память для массива из одного элемента (текущее значение `ctr`).

Но цикл в общем случае не останавливается после первой итерации и пытается писать в `averagenum` за пределами выделенной памяти. Результат печален...

То, что вы потом меняете значение `ctr` - массив не меняется.

Примерно как в ресторане вы бросаете кошелек официанту и говорите "гуляю на все", официант смотрит внутрь, берет деньги и тащит вам на ваш целый рубль три корочки хлеба :). После этого вы докладываете в кошелек пару тысяч - но заказ-то уже сделан - с чего официанту интересоваться, что у вас там происходит?...

Answer (score 3):

Почему-то часто вижу такую ошибку.

Когда вы пишете что-то вроде:

```
int ctr=1;
int averagenum[ctr];
```

`averagenum` получает размер `1`. Если потом поменять `ctr`, размер массива не изменится.